# Excel Result not giving me anything, but it runs fine

Tags: .net, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, export-to-excel

I use this AJAX to call my Excel Export action on the controller:

```
$("#ExportToExcel").click(function () {
        // ajax call to do the export
        var urlString = "<%= System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/mvc/Indications.cfc/ExportToExcel")%>";
        var Jsondata =
                {
                    id: GetGUIDValue(),
                    viewName: "<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Views/Indications/TermSheetViews/Swap/CashFlows.aspx")%>",
                    fileName: 'Cashflows.xls'
                }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: urlString,
            data: Jsondata,
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
    });
```

Here is what the action looks like:

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel(Guid? id, string viewName, string fileName)
        {
            IndicationBase indication = CachedTransactionManager<IndicationBase>.GetCachedTransactions(id.Value);
            return new ExcelResult<Chatham.Web.Models.Indications.ModelBase>
            (
                ControllerContext,
                viewName,
                fileName,
                indication.Model
            );
        }
```

Firebug runs through fine, no errors, and the code doesn't error when running either, but nothing pops up on the screen. I am expecting to see a save dialog box to save the excel file.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here is my custom action,

```
public class ExcelResult<Model> : ActionResult
    {
        string _fileName;
        string _viewPath;
        Model _model;
        ControllerContext _context;

        public ExcelResult(ControllerContext context, string viewPath, string fileName, Model model)
        {
            this._context = context;
            this._fileName = fileName;
            this._viewPath = viewPath;
            this._model = model;
        }
         protected string RenderViewToString()
        {
            using (var writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                var view = new WebFormView(_viewPath);
                var vdd = new ViewDataDictionary<Model>(_model);
                var viewCxt = new ViewContext(_context, view, vdd, new TempDataDictionary(), writer);
                viewCxt.View.Render(viewCxt, writer);
                return writer.ToString();
            }
        }
        void WriteFile(string content)
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + _fileName);
            context.Response.Charset = "";
            context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            context.Response.Write(content);
            context.Response.End();
        }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            string content = this.RenderViewToString();
            this.WriteFile(content);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call a file download on a ajax query because the browser will not trigger the file download popup.

Instead of doing an ajax call to your controller method, simply use a

```
windows.open("yoururl/ExportToExcel?id=yourid&etc...", null, null, null);
```

And don"t forget to add your arguments.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I have my export to Excel implemented using **[FileContentResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult.aspx)**. It takes care of settings response headers for you. There's no point to reinvent the wheel. ;-)

Don't know if it will be useful but I can recommend **[EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com)** library to load and process Excel files.

Could you try converting your POST to GET and just render  tag directly?
I don't think IE is picking up content-disposition during AJAX request.

Comment: I'd like to do that but I wouldn't know how to re-write that override for it.

Comment: You don't have to override anything. Just return new FileContentResult() from your action. It derives from Action Result.

Comment: I'm not so sure I understand what you are saying, lol. Sorry =/

Comment: We are rendering the partial view, and then converting this to Excel, and then setting up the HTTP Response and sending this back. If I use file content result I need a byte[] array, but I already have this code to convert to excel using rendering partial views

Comment: Changing POST to GET didnt seem to do anything. It did seem to change the Firebug response, but not getting any result in IE or Firefox.

Comment: Have you got rid of AJAX altogether and just rendered an <a> tag? - this works for me...