# Export to Excel and ModelBase

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

My needs are simple - just export the MVC view data table to Excel. 
I searched many different ways to have a Razor MVC4 view export to Excel and found this to be a good simple method, but I am a little stuck with how to implement it correctly as I don't understand the ModelBase concept. I found a couple examples using this method, but cannot get them working with my solution.

http://landokal.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/asp-net-mvc-export-to-excel-trick/

```
   public class ExcelResult<Model> : ActionResult
{
    string _fileName;
    string _viewPath;
    Model _model;
    ControllerContext _context;

    public ExcelResult(ControllerContext context, string viewPath, string fileName, Model model)
    {
        this._context = context;
        this._fileName = fileName;
        this._viewPath = viewPath;
        this._model = model;
    }
    protected string RenderViewToString()
    {
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            var view = new WebFormView(_context, _viewPath);
            var vdd = new ViewDataDictionary<Model>(_model);
            var viewCxt = new ViewContext(_context, view, vdd, new TempDataDictionary(), writer);
            viewCxt.View.Render(viewCxt, writer);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
    void WriteFile(string content)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + _fileName + "\"");
        context.Response.Charset = "";
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        context.Response.Write(content);
        context.Response.End();
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        string content = this.RenderViewToString();
        this.WriteFile(content);
    }
}
```

I also found this similar post using the same method.
[Excel Result not giving me anything, but it runs fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106891/excel-result-not-giving-me-anything-but-it-runs-fine)

I am not using AJAX like above, but just a simple actionlink on an existing page that displays a table view of data results from DB.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export to Excel", "ExcelExport")
```

I tried to follow the examples above and created an ActionResult below, but I don't understand what I am suppose to substitute for "ModelBase" below as it doesn't like this syntax.

```
        public ActionResult ExcelExport()
    {
       List<TrainingSwipe> viewModel = _db.TrainingSwipes
            .OrderBy(v => v.SwipeDateTime).ToList();
       return View(viewModel);
       return new ExcelResult<ModelBase>
           (
               ControllerContext,
               "Export.aspx",
               "ExcelExport",
               viewModel
           );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have been doing a lot of Excel exporting recently in my MVC Projects and have been using NPOI's excel package. Alternatives are EP Plus which I think is built over the top of NPOI (Haven't used it myself)

As for the ModelBase I'm not entirely sure what that is I suspect some abstract class that was created by the blogger but here is a possible solution for you.

But I digress. I have built a simple ExcelHelper Class which wraps the NPOI stuff under the hood to perform all the Excel creation and then you just return the file as a FileResult.

You can access the project here:

https://github.com/JellyMaster/ExcelHelper

If you look at the unit tests you will see how this works. But in terms of using it within an actionresult here is some sample code for you.

```
   public ActionResult Export()
        {
            List<MyModel> model = new List<MyModel>();

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

            model = myServiceLayer.GetExportResults();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(model.ToDataTable<MyModel>());

            try
            {
                stream = ExcelHelper.CreateExcelSheet(ds, ExcelHelper.ExcelType.Xlsx);
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
            }



            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                string exportName = "myexcelfile.xlsx";

                return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.ms-excel", exportName);
            }



        }
```

This works by doing some reflection to convert you class objects to a dataset and then exporting that data to a dataset which is fed into the excelhelper and outputs the contents to a stream and you then pass that back as a file result.

I actually need to push an update which resolves a couple of minor niggles I spotted but it works perfectly fine in its current form. If you need any more info or help then feel free to get in touch.

Edit: I have actually just pushed the update out now to my github project.

Comment: Thx, I am looking for a simple solution, hoping to fix a couple lines of code and be done with it, but if not, I may end up looking into NPOI and your solution.

Comment: Not a problem. I was looking for a simple solution myself and one that didn't require me to do too much coding to put the data into a spreadsheet hence my solution.